# How to use compass on Grunt with libsass instead of ruby sass?

Tags: ruby, sass, gruntjs, compass, libsass

We've been using the Ruby version of the sass compiler with compass and [grunt-contrib-sass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass) for quite a while but it's very slow.

Since libsass is faster than its Ruby pendant, we replaced grunt-contrib-sass with [grunt-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass).

Unfortunately, the docs for [grunt-contrib-compass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-compass) say:

> This task requires you to have Ruby, Sass, and Compass >=1.0.1
>   installed

Also, when I run our build, I get:

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
>> Error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass
>>        Parent style sheet: src/assets/sass/catalog.scss
>>         on line 15 of src/assets/sass/catalog.scss
>> >> @import "compass";
>>    ^
Warning:  Use --force to continue.
```

So, if grunt-contrib-compass is not compatible with grunt-sass how can I use compass with libsass then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It was as easy as installing [compass-importer](https://github.com/haithembelhaj/compass-importer):

```
$ npm install --save-dev compass-importer
```

And then set `importer: compass` in Gruntfile.js